# Latest version tinyMCE.remove() method appears to save changes to the textarea by default (with no explicit saving)

Tags: tinymce

I am using a single instance on a page with many other fields and when the other fields gain focus, I call tinyMCE.remove() to remove the iframe and show the marked up text in the textarea it was refrencing.  However, even without explicitly saving the content, it appreas that the remove() method will actually save whatever changes were made.  This is actually acceptable for our use of the control, but I there is no documentation stating this will happen.  So I'm concerned that a future version may 'fix' this and then I'll have to be sure to explicitly save the content first.  Also the 'cancel' doesn't appear to do anything when including it.

Has anyone else experience this?

I was able to confirm this with the following:
Where txtDetails is the textarea used on the tinyMCE init.

```
        $("textarea").focus(function () {
            console.log($("#txtDetails").val());
            tinymce.activeEditor.remove();
            console.log($("#txtDetails").val());
        });
```

This is the tinyMCE init used:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: '#' + clientID, //'#tinyEditor',
            plugins: 'code link', //  save
            menubar: false,
            toolbar: 'link bold italic underline forecolor', //  save cancel
            toolbar_mode: 'floating',
            paste_block_drop: true,
            paste_merge_formats: true,
            paste_as_text: false,
            paste_webkit_styles: 'color font-size',
            smart_paste: false,
            statusbar: false,
            //save_enablewhendirty: false,
            force_br_newlines: true,
            newline_behavior: 'linebreak',
            link_target_list: [
                { title: 'New page', value: '_blank' }
            ],
            default_link_target: '_blank',
            link_assume_external_targets: 'https',
            init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
                var $html = document.getElementById(clientID).value;
                editor.setContent($html);
            } //,
        //    save_onsavecallback: () => {
        //        tinymce.remove();
        //    },
        //    save_oncancelcallback: () => {
        //        tinymce.remove();
        //    }
```

I'm getting the same behavior with or without the save plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. And it is not specific to the latest version.

TinyMCE sticks to the textarea/div/etc. to change their content. But once TinyMCE is removed - it leaves the content as is.

Imagine that you need to edit the textarea content successively with two different editors. It would be much more complicated if one of the editors cleans the textarea on `remove()`.

If you need to clean the textarea before `remove()`, you can call something like `setContent('')`. But don't forget to save the content somewhere with `getContent()`.

I'd also recommend considering calling [destroy()](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#destroy) instead of remove, as, besides the editor itself, it removes all events, element references, etc., preventing memory leaks. `destroy()` calls `remove()` during execution.